# Installing Jenkins on Ubuntu tells me "Package 'jenkins' has no installation candidate"

Tags: jenkins, ubuntu-20.04

I need to install Jenkins on Ubuntu 20.4.1.

I've completed the following:

- `apt-get -y install openjdk-8-jdk` (it's Java 14.0.1)
- `wget -q -O - http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian-stable/jenkins-ci.org.key | apt-key add -` (responds "OK")
- `sudo sh -c 'echo deb https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'` (file exists and has this one line in it)
- `sudo apt update`, responds:

> ```
> Hit:1 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
> Hit:2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
> Hit:3 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
> Hit:4 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
> Ign:5 https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ InRelease
> Get:6 https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ Release [2,044 B]
> Get:7 https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ Release.gpg [833 B]
> Ign:7 https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ Release.gpg
> Reading package lists... Done
> W: GPG error: https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ Release: The following signatures couldn't 
> be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY FCEF32E745F2C3D5
> E: The repository 'http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ Release' is not signed.
> N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.      
> N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
> ```

- `sudo apt install jenkins`, responds:

> ```
> root@ubuntu-server:~# sudo apt install jenkins
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree       
> Reading state information... Done
> Package jenkins is not available, but is referred to by another package.
> This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
> is only available from another source
> E: Package 'jenkins' has no installation candidate
> ```

**What do I have to do so that `apt` finds the Jenkins package so it can be installed?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're following unofficial or out of date instructions.

Because of this, you imported the wrong GPG key. Jenkins changed their GPG key on 16 April 2020. You need to import the correct key following the [current official directions](https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/).

> ```
> wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins.io.key | sudo apt-key add -
> ```

Comment: Absolutely. That was it, thanks.

Comment: That's work fine :)

Comment: It's been over a year, but I get the same error following the official instructions on jenkins.io. `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` before importing the key fixes it for me

Answer (score 3):

To install Jenkins on Ubuntu, follow below set of commands:

```
wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins.io.key | 
  sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo deb https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ > \
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jenkins
```

Answer (score -1):

$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys FCEF32E745F2C3D5
&& sudo apt-get update

Comment: What key is that? How can the people who read this answer be sure it is the correct key?